# Когда имеет смысл делегирование событий в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если в нативном javascript есть разница с точки зрения написания кода, то в jQuery с этим всё гораздо проще.

Без делегирования событий:

```
$('ul li').on('click', handler)
```

С делегированием событий:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', handler)
```

Как я понимаю, разница в том что с делегированием событий мы навешиваем только 1 обработчик вместо `<li> * N` обработчиков, и у нас тратится меньше ресурсов. Но на сколько это критично в современных реалиях? Было бы здорово увидеть пример из жизни.

Какой из подходов считается более хорошей практикой?

И когда действительно необходимо использовать делегирование событий?

Comment: Есть существенная разница если этот список меняется динамически. Если добавить в него ещё новых li, то второй обработчик будет на них срабатывать, а первый — нет. И это, пожалуй, самое важное разлличие

Comment: тут главное понять, к чему и для чего привязывается событие. в первом случае только к *существующим* элементам документа. Во втором -  к существующему родителю, и не важно есть ли на настоящий момент потомки, удовлетворяющие нужному селектору.